# Configure Camel Jetty endoint without specifying protocol, host and port

Tags: apache-camel, jetty, war

In order to accept (in a Camel WAR application) uploaded files I need to expose a jetty endpoint and, in the jetty configuration, I'd like to not specify protocol, host, port and context root (I'd like to inherit these informations from the container WAR).

Is possible to do so? I've found no informations about this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved as follows: instead of using jetty I used servlet

```
<camel:route id="servlet-route">
    <camel:from id="servletfrom" uri="servlet://provaservlet?disableStreamCache=true"/>
    <to id="servletto" uri="provaUploadProcessorId"/>
</camel:route>
```

In the processor `provaUploadProcessorId` I got the servlet request from the exchange body

```
HttpServletRequest request = exchange.getIn().getBody(HttpServletRequest.class);
```

and then I was able to read params and files as shown below

```
        List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
        for (FileItem item : items) {
            if (item.isFormField()) {
                // Process regular form field (input
                // type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
                String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
                String fieldValue = item.getString();
                log.info("param name " + fieldName + ", param value " + fieldValue);
            } else {
                // Process form file field (input type="file").
                String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
                String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
                log.info("file param name " + fieldName + ", file param value " + fileName);
                InputStream fileContent = item.getInputStream();
                // do what you want with the file content and then close it
                fileContent.close();
            }
        }
```

Keep in mind to load these depencencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```